# Is it possible to generate a tooltip for keyboard traversal?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Generally if we provide a title tag it shows as a tool tip. So on mouse hover we can see this tool tip. My question is if I traverse the elements through keyboard, Is it possible to generate a tool tip at that time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gedrox mentions, the HTML standard attribute "title" is only used for mouse over effects. However, you can do this via JavaScript using the onfocus event, see [Display a fixed "ToolTip" when an input receives focus, using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171575/display-a-fixed-tooltip-when-an-input-receives-focus-using-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

This could be helpful – http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20-TECHS/H33.html.

```
Some graphical user agents will display a tool tip when the mouse hovers 
above an anchor element containing a title attribute. However, current user 
agents do not provide access to title attribute content via the keyboard.
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a **javascript** tooltip:

you can use onfocus (and onblur) to get when the keyboard is going over (and out) an element.
you can get the position of the element with position. so you can display a tool tip.

I know onfocus and blur work for input fields and links, not shure if it is cross browser for other elements

Answer (score 1):

not the default one. you can draw your own using a floating div that shows like the tooltip and fill it up with text it gets from the title attribute.